# RESTAssured disable URL encoding not working correctly

Tags: java, url, url-encoding, rest-assured

I am testing a HTTP Post request with an URL like following:

> https://myurl.com/api/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fmessages?Api-Token=12332429nmdsafs

I have URL encoding disabled and here my post request:

```
RestAssured.given()
.contentType(JSON)
.log()
.all()
.urlEncodingEnabled(false)
.baseUri(RestAssured.baseURI)
.basePath(url)
.pathParam(LOG_PATH_PARAM_NAME, urlEncodeString(requireNonNull(logPath)))
.body(myJsonBody)
.when()
.post("/logs/{logPath}")
.then()
.statusCode(OK.getStatusCode());
```

I also tried it like this:

```
RestAssured.given()
.contentType(JSON)
.log()
.all()
.urlEncodingEnabled(false)
.baseUri(RestAssured.baseURI)
.basePath(url)
.body(myJsonBody)
.when()
.post("/logs/" + urlEncodeString(requireNonNull(logPath)))
.then()
.statusCode(OK.getStatusCode());
```

And here the urlEncodeString method:

```
private static String urlEncodeString(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
    }
```

The problem now is that my URL mentioned above gets encoded to following:

> https://myurl.com/api/logs/var/log/messages?Api-Token=12332429nmdsafs

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Or knows a workaround?
I already tried to double escape the path.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that disabling URL encoding only works for the URL parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Although you are correct that `given().urlEncodingEnabled(isEnabled).spec()...` will only disable encoding for URL parameters, you can also do the same for the URL itself using

`RequestSpecification mySpec = new RequestSpecBuilder().setUrlEncodingEnabled(false)`

For example, if I want to make a get request to this (exact) URL without encoding it `http://api.cheapbooks.com/mathbooks/location/$amazonbooks%2Fscience%2Fmath`

The default behavior of RestAssured will double encode the URL to this: `http://api.cheapbooks.com/mathbooks/location/%24amazonbook%252Fscience%2Fmath`

But if you create a  RequestSpecification like the `mySpec` above, where `setUrlEncodingEnabled(false)` and you make a http request by either doing :

`given().spec(mySpec)...`

or

`spec.setBaseUri(...)`

You should get the desired result this way